# How to improve Chebyshev bound on the prime counting inequality?

Tags: number-theory, prime-gaps, chebyshev-function

So, I've understood the proof of `A*x/logx < pi(x) < B*x/logx` for (A,B) = (0.5,2), but how can I make this difference smaller? Does any one know the methods used by him and further by J.J. Sylvester?
I'd like references in english for I found some papers in french, but could figure out anything.
Thanks

Ps: pi(x) is the prime counting function

Comment: See bottom of page 86 of https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main3.pdf Also, you may enjoy https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_23_cheby_error.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, this is an unexpected honor - thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still searching but there is a great expository paper by Diamond, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7147/23e8854b484a3ebcadfa518461af7eb98c73.pdf

Also, by Sylvester:

pages 530–545 of:

https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=umhistmath;idno=AAS8085.0003.001

pages 687–731 of:

https://archive.org/details/collectedmathem04sylvrich

Hope this helps!